# Error while changing the name of RSU

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have one error when i changed the name of the default eNodeB (RSU) in veins-lte.

> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerForker)
>   scenario.manager (id=6) at event #105, t=0.1: check_and_cast(): cannot
>   cast NULL pointer to type 'LteMacEnb *'.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please provide the exact changes you did which led to the error. Also please tell us, which version of Veins-LTE you are using.

Comment: Hi  Julian Heinovski, I'm using Omnet++4.6 and Veins-LTE 1.3.
The default name of eNodeB (RSU) in the Heterogeneous example is eNodeB1.
I only changed the name from eNodeB1 to eNodeB2 in Highway.ned, omnetpp.ini and topology-config.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the code, Veins LTE 1.3 does not seem to be prepared to handle nodes that are attached to an eNodeB named other than `eNodeB1`.

A quick search for this text reveals [line 480](https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/blob/veins-lte-1.3/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L480) and [line 509](https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/blob/veins-lte-1.3/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L509) of `TraCIScenarioManager.cc`, both of which seem force each new node to attach to an eNodeB named `eNodeB1` when it is created and to detach from an eNodeB named `eNodeB1` when the node is destroyed.

Both should be easy enough to change in the code, but from your question it appears like you might be trying to run a multi-eNodeB scenario, which I am not sure is supported in Veins LTE 1.3, as it does not include the most recent version of SimuLTE.